# Use Postcss with Vuepress

Tags: vue.js, postcss, postcss-loader, vuepress

I'm trying to use Postcss plugins with my Vuepress custom theme, but I can't get it to work. Vuepress' documentation is extremely vague and anything from postcss-loader works.

Can someone please tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Using postcss is fairly easy with Vuepress. You also do not need to add `postcss-loader`. Vuepress comes with it, as it uses postcss be default. The only thing you need is to pass configuration option. Here are steps tested to work:

Install postcss plugins you want to use (e.g. `yarn add postcss-preset-env -D`)

In `.vuepress/config.js` add this:

```
module.exports = {
    postcss: {
        plugins: [
            require('postcss-preset-env')({/*plugin options*/})
        ]
    }
}
```

This is enough to have the plugin enabled. More:
https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#postcss

Comment: Note that the docs say that the default postcss configuration will be *overwritten* and not _extended_. Currently it seems to only include the `autoprefixer` plugin: `{ plugins: [require('autoprefixer')] }`. Is there a way to inspect the configuration that is currently used before I start adding my stuff there?

Comment: PS: The `autoprefixer`is added by `postcss-preset-env` in the case above, so this is fine.